# Enabling Catalog Search -> Elasticsearc6+ results error in frontend

Tags: magento2.3.2, elasticsearch

**In Magento 2.3.2** I enabled Elasticsearch6+ in Catalog Search -> Search Engine. It resulted this error in front end:

> Class
>   Magento\Elasticsearch6\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper
>   does not exist

**Any ideas what this is about?**

Comment: have you install elasticsearch in your webserver ?

Comment: Yes indeed we have and connection test button in Magento admin results a successful connection to elastic.

Comment: I have another test installation with 2.3.3 and in that I do not have that issue. There is another issue and Magento does not show products in categories anymore when elastic is enabled.

Comment: after enabling elastic have you done reindexing ?

Comment: After reindexing it worked in M2.3.3.

Comment: So I m adding as a answer

Comment: It worked on 2.3.3 but not on 2.3.2 and the question was about the latter.